How to implement a double relation between entities with hibernate 6.5
I have a database on which 2 tables have a double relationship :
Database graph
The Spot may be the parent of several SpotConditions, so there is a basic OneToMany relationship.
But in addition, each Spot has to retain the current SpotCondition, this is done with the "spt_current_condition" as foreign key.
I work with Spring Boot (then Hibernate in background), and the goal is to have a bidirectional relationship between the Spot and the current SpotCondition.
I was able to make it work with Spring Boot 2.7.1 (Hibernate 5), but I have migrated to Spring Boot 3 (Hibernate 6.5), and now I have a java.lang.StackOverflowError: null when trying to get the Spot with the embeded CurrentSpotCondition (And this SpotCondition has to have the Spot embeded as well).
There is a loop situation here and I think this is the base of the issue. I don't understand why this was working before and not anymore. Any input to give me an idea would be appreciated :-)
Thank you a lot for your help.
These are my 2 entities :
@Entity
@Table( name = "t_spot_spt" )
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Spot {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    @Column( name = "spt_id" )
    private Integer             id;

    @OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinColumn( name = "spt_current_condition" )
    private SpotCondition       currentCondition;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "spot", fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    private List<SpotCondition> conditions;

    @Column( name = "spt_bla_id" )
    private Integer             bladeId;


@Entity
@Table( name = "t_spot_condition_scd" )
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString( onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true )
public abstract class SpotCondition implements Diffable<SpotCondition> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    @Column( name = "scd_id" )
    @ToString.Include
    protected Integer                       id;

    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinColumn( name = "scd_spt_id" )
    protected Spot                          spot;

I am not sure if this is the proper way to do the mapping, but this is logic to me.
These are the classes I use to retrieve the data
Repository :
public interface SpotRepository extends JpaRepository<Spot, Integer> {

    List<Spot> findByBladeId( Integer bladeId );


Service :
    @Override
    @Transactional( readOnly = true )
    public Integer findWorstDamageSeverityIdByBlade( Integer bladeId ) {
        short level = Short.MIN_VALUE;
        Integer sevId = null;
        boolean repairPresent = false;
        for ( Spot spt : spotRepository.findByBladeId( bladeId ) ) {
            SpotCondition sc = spt.getCurrentCondition();
            //DO SOME STUFF
        ... 


This is the begining ot the stack trace :
2024-07-25T21:09:55.332+02:00[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m19556[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[p-nio-80-exec-6][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/bladeexpert] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.NavigablePathMapToInitializer.get(NavigablePathMapToInitializer.java:33) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.ResultsHelper$1.resolveInitializer(ResultsHelper.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.ResultsHelper$1.resolveInitializer(ResultsHelper.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.collection.internal.CollectionFetch.createAssembler(CollectionFetch.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.collection.internal.DelayedCollectionFetch.createAssembler(DelayedCollectionFetch.java:50) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.<init>(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:205) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityJoinedFetchInitializer.<init>(EntityJoinedFetchInitializer.java:48) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityFetchJoinedImpl.createInitializer(EntityFetchJoinedImpl.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityFetchJoinedImpl.createInitializer(EntityFetchJoinedImpl.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityFetchJoinedImpl.createInitializer(EntityFetchJoinedImpl.java:36) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.ResultsHelper$1.resolveInitializer(ResultsHelper.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.ResultsHelper$1.resolveInitializer(ResultsHelper.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityFetchJoinedImpl.createAssembler(EntityFetchJoinedImpl.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.<init>(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:205) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityJoinedFetchInitializer.<init>(EntityJoinedFetchInitializer.java:48) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityFetchJoinedImpl.createInitializer(EntityFetchJoinedImpl.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityFetchJoinedImpl.createInitializer(EntityFetchJoinedImpl.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityFetchJoinedImpl.createInitializer(EntityFetchJoinedImpl.java:36) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.ResultsHelper$1.resolveInitializer(ResultsHelper.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.ResultsHelper$1.resolveInitializer(ResultsHelper.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityFetchJoinedImpl.createAssembler(EntityFetchJoinedImpl.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.<init>(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:205) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityJoinedFetchInitializer.<init>(EntityJoinedFetchInitializer.java:48) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityFetchJoinedImpl.createInitializer(EntityFetchJoinedImpl.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityFetchJoinedImpl.createInitializer(EntityFetchJoinedImpl.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityFetchJoinedImpl.createInitializer(EntityFetchJoinedImpl.java:36) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.ResultsHelper$1.resolveInitializer(ResultsHelper.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.ResultsHelper$1.resolveInitializer(ResultsHelper.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityFetchJoinedImpl.createAssembler(EntityFetchJoinedImpl.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.<init>(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:205) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityResultInitializer.<init>(EntityResultInitializer.java:34) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityResultImpl.createInitializer(EntityResultImpl.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityResultImpl.createInitializer(EntityResultImpl.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityResultImpl.createInitializer(EntityResultImpl.java:30) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.ResultsHelper$1.resolveInitializer(ResultsHelper.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.ResultsHelper$1.resolveInitializer(ResultsHelper.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityResultImpl.createResultAssembler(EntityResultImpl.java:86) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.StandardJdbcValuesMapping.resolveAssemblers(StandardJdbcValuesMapping.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.ResultsHelper.createRowReader(ResultsHelper.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.ResultsHelper.createRowReader(ResultsHelper.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:83) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleUniqueKeyEntityLoaderStandard.load(SingleUniqueKeyEntityLoaderStandard.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.loadByUniqueKey(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2645) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.loadByUniqueKey(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2637) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntitySelectFetchByUniqueKeyInitializer.initializeInstance(EntitySelectFetchByUniqueKeyInitializer.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.InitializersList.initializeInstance(InitializersList.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.coordinateInitializers(StandardRowReader.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]

I tried to change the behaviour of the OneToOne mapping to LAZY instead of EAGER.
@Entity
@Table( name = "t_spot_spt" )
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Spot {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    @Column( name = "spt_id" )
    private Integer             id;

    @OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY ) //CHANGED FROM EAGER TO LAZY
    @JoinColumn( name = "spt_current_condition" )
    private SpotCondition       currentCondition;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "spot", fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    private List<SpotCondition> conditions;

    @Column( name = "spt_bla_id" )
    private Integer             bladeId;

This worked, but then When I try to retrieve the CurrentSpotCondition from the Spot, I have a wzarning message : [2m2024-07-25T21:30:11.878+02:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m19556[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[p-nio-80-exec-3][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.h.e.i.StatefulPersistenceContext      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000179: Narrowing proxy to class com.bladeexpert.core.entity.spot.damage.OutdoorDamageSpotCondition - this operation breaks ==
And finally the CurrentSpotContition is not retrieved.
